# T-SQL: How to add bits in binary fields?

Tags: sql-server, binary

I have a table

```
create table t (id int, b binary(128))

insert into t(id, b) values (1, 0x010000)
insert into t(id, b) values (1, 0x000204)
insert into t(id, b) values (2, 0x000004)
insert into t(id, b) values (2, 0x010204)
insert into t(id, b) values (2, 0x010004)
```

I need to receive finally summary table contains 2 records
where b is a OR'ed bits

```
create table result (id int, b binary(128)) 

1 0x010204
2 0x010004
```

It seems I need to do this

select id, FUN(b) from t group by id

The question is: I need to create and use SQLCLR aggregate function FUN.
Is there another way?

Comment: There is the other way - writing FUN as a summarizing function for binary(128) type. If so, you should probably edit initial post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLCLR is not required, though it would be more readable ;-). I was able to do this via the following which required a cursor but I couldn't find a way around it (APPLY would be nice but  doesn't quite work in this context).

```
/* given sample data but as temp table and BINARY(5) instead of BINARY(128) */
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT, B BINARY(5));  --DROP TABLE #t
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 0x010000); INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 0x000204);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2, 0x000004); INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2, 0x010204);
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2, 0x010004);
SELECT *, CONVERT(BIGINT, b) AS [converted] from #t
------------------------
DECLARE @Totals TABLE (ID INT, B BIGINT);
DECLARE @ID INT, @B BIGINT;

DECLARE curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL
FOR  SELECT src.id, CONVERT(BIGINT, src.b) FROM #t src;

OPEN curs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @ID, @B;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ttl
    SET    ttl.B |= @B
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*, @B AS [CurrentB] -- debug
    FROM   @Totals ttl WHERE  ttl.ID = @ID;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Totals (ID, B) VALUES (@ID, @B);
    END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @ID, @B;
END;

CLOSE curs; DEALLOCATE curs;

SELECT 'Result' AS [~~], ttl.ID, ttl.B, CONVERT(BINARY(5), ttl.B) AS [FinalB]
FROM @Totals ttl;
```

Of course, if you truly need a `BINARY(128)`, then this might not work.

Comment: Thanx, I will test it, but the problem is:  in case of 150 000 000 records it will be very long operation.

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, it wouldn't be great on 150 Million records, but that was never mentioned ;-). I made a minor change that would help (no initial insert via DISTINCT), but if you have 150 MM records, then that leads to additional questions such as: are you wanting an on-the-fly calculation? If yes, are there other fields in the source table to either group on or do you want to query all rows at the same time? If not on-the-fly, is there a unique field in the table that will allow for batching? Even using SQLCLR isn't going to be great for a single query intending on reading all 150 MM rows.

Comment: I am trying to reorganize some tables in my db. These 150 M rows are the implementation of M:N, i.e. I have a main table node(id, name ...), roles table (role_id, name ...) (500 rows) and table node_right( node_id, role_id). It means: can role have access to node (0 or 1). I want to reduce this table and use table (node_id, rolesbinary) . It will be 1:1 with node and every roles_binary field contains 0/1 in bit position for corresponding role.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is _very_ helpful, and changes the conversation. I don't know how to take this conversation out of the comments area but we need to. You want a migration script to assist what might be a bad solution to a problem that might not exist. And there are several issues to deal with, such as bit-wise ORs do not work against (VAR)BINARY as you expect so you need to use BIGINT, but that only allows for 62 values and you need 500. You need to take a step back and address _why_ you are trying to get away from what appears to be a proper model. A simple index change might do it.

Comment: Thank you, you absolutely right understood my task :-). Simply saying: I want to reduce write and read operations to this large table. The main table is hierarchy implementation. When user try to change the permissions at the high level of tree then need to update many records in the current implementation. My idea will allow to reduce updates and inserts. But the question is how to organize optimal reading....

Comment: Again, this requires a full conversation. I'm not sure that switching to a bit-masked field will solve the problem as it requires additional processing to extract the unique bit values out of the combined field for all operations. There might be other approaches/options but that requires further investigation. And all of this is outside of the scope of this question. As it is stated, I have answered the original question. I am willing to help you find a solution to the real issue, but that should be a new question seeking advice on design/data model for the current model and business rules.